# Solving linear programming with Prolog

Tags: prolog, linear-programming, instantiation-error

I am trying to solve first linear programming problem example on http://www.zweigmedia.com/RealWorld/tutorialsf4/framesLinProGr.html. X and Y are zero or positives, their sum can be upto 50, 2X+Y can be upto 60. The function X+3Y has to be maximized.

I am using following code:

```
mysol2(X,Y,Z):-
    X in 0..sup,  % Error: Syntax error: Operator expected
    Y in 0..sup,
    X + Y =< 50,
    2 * X + Y =< 60,
    Z is max(X + 3*Y).
```

However, it does not even load (error is indicated above).

With following code:

```
mysol2(X,Y,Z):-
    X >= 0,
    Y >= 0,
    X + Y =< 50,
    2 * X + Y =< 60,
    Z is max(X + 3*Y).
```

The program loads, but on running:

```
ERROR: >=/2: Arguments are not sufficiently instantiated
```

How can I correct these errors?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`(>=)/2` and `(is)/2` are **very low-level** predicates. You can only use them in very special circumstances. In most cases, these predicates will lead to **instantiation errors** because one or both arguments are not sufficiently instantiated.

**Constraints** are a declarative solution in such cases, working correctly in all cases.

For example, you can use **CLP(Q)** as available in SICStus Prolog with minimal modifications of your code:

```
:- use_module(library(clpq)).

solution(X, Y) :-
    { X >= 0,
      Y >= 0,
      X + Y =< 50,
      2*X + Y =< 60 }.
```

Sample query and result:

```
| ?- solutionX, Y), maximize(X+3*Y).
X = 0,
Y = 50  ? ;
no
```

The most widely used Prolog and Prolog-like systems (SICStus, ECLiPSe etc.) all ship with powerful constraint libraries, which are meant to be used notably when reasoning over integers and rationals.

Comment: Which is such one library in SWI-Prolog?

Comment: SWI-Prolog ships with a [port](http://eu.swi-prolog.org/man/clpqr.html) of the SICStus CLP(Q) library. However, the SWI implementation contains mistakes, so I cannot recommend it.

Comment: Note that `X = 0+0, solution(X, 50).` succeeds, while `solution(X, 50), X = 0+0.` fails. However, `(is)/2`, `(>=)/2` ... do not have this problem.

Comment: @false : I am not clear about the point that you are making. Do you have a code solution using 'is' or '>='?

Comment: @mso: (no, a solution with `is` or `>=` alone is next to impossible) What I said was this: In an ideal declarative implementation, it always holds that for two goals `G_0` and `H_0` it holds:  `G_0, H_0` is the same as `H_0, G_0`. But with `G_0 = ( X = 0 + 0)` and `H_0 = solution(X, 50)` this is not the case.